# Retrieve Django ManyToMany results outside of the current model

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm brand new to Django.

- I have a list of **stores**. Each of those stores carry **brands** of products.
- For a store, I can list the brands that they carry.
- **For a brand, I want to list the stores that carry that brand.**

Here are my models (simplified):

```
class Store(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    brands = models.ManyToManyField('Brand',related_name='brand')

class Brand(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Here is my view for the template:

```
def brand_detail_slug(request, slug):
    brand = Brand.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'storefinder/brand_detail.html', {'brand': brand})
```

---

I can retrieve info for the brands successfully in my view:

```
{% for p in brand.product_types.all %}
    <li>{{ p }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't know how to do this for stores, since it's not really defined in the Brands. It's a separate model.... this is where I get confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many-to-Many relationships are mutual. So stores can be seen from brands and vice-versa.

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to minimize the number of DB queries that will be required to do this:

```
brands = Brand.objects.filter(slug=slug).prefetch_related('stores')
stores = [b.stores.all() for b in brands] # all related stores to those brands
```

**Update**

`related_name` was not properly defined. Use the name of the model that contains the M2M relationship:

```
brands = models.ManyToManyField('Brand', related_name='stores')
```

Comment: Trying to do this, but my new view isn't working: `def brand_detail_slug(request, slug):
 brand = Brand.objects.filter(slug=slug).prefetch_related('stores')
 stores = brand.stores.all() 
 return render(request, 'storefinder/brand_detail.html', {'brand': brand})`

AttributeError at /stores/brand/bazzill-basics/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'stores'

Line 36:  stores = brand.stores.all()

Comment: That didn't work because your `related_name` was not properly defined. See my update.

Comment: Still getting the exact same error. I updated my Store model so that the "brands" has a related name of 'stores' and nothing changed. I also tried changing the the related name and the prefetch_related to "brands" and the error never changed: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'stores' Line 36: stores = brand.stores.all()`

Comment: If I leave out the line it's complaining about `stores = Brand.stores.all()`, my page no longer errors but the data set is empty (nothing shows except for the template design). Dumping my 'brand' variable in the template says: ` '_prefetch_done': False,
 '_prefetch_related_lookups': ['stores'],`

Comment: I updated my answer. `brand` is a QuerySet that can return a list of objects (could be one item) so you need to do `brand[0].stores.all()` to retrieve the stores for the first brand object or just retrieve everything like I've shown in my update

Comment: Yay, almost there! I see the stores data in my template, but I still have the issue now where the original brand info isn't working in my template. `{{ brand.company }}` won't return anything, but my `{{ stores.all }}` is working fine. In my view, the `get(slug=slug)` worked, but your `filter(slug=slug)` isn't, or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: `{{ brand.0.company }}` or `{{ brands.0.company }}` if you've changed the name

Comment: Thanks it's working 100% now. :) :) I only noticed one thing: if I take out the `prefetch_related`, it still functions 100% the same. Is it just for performance?

Comment: Yes, performance. `prefetch_related` reduces the number of queries on m2m DB ops

Answer (score -1):

I think I've found a solution online, not sure if it's perfect but it's working for me:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    brands = models.ManyToManyField('Brand', blank=True)

class Brand(models.Model):
    stores = models.ManyToManyField('Store', through=Store.brands.through, blank=True)
```

Comment: Don't do this. This is unnecessary. There are several ways to traverse M2M relationships in django. See Moses's answer.

Comment: Lawrence is right. this would help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: I clearly need to do some tutorials on models and queries... the basic concept is super easy but when it gets more intricate I run into all sorts of road blocks (ie. linking brands to stores, then linking stores to cities and showing the cities that have stores, etc.)